# How to I make people talk with ClickEvent books in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to find a way to make people talk with books in minecraft.  I've seen it done before and I want to make my own custom book. I have been looking all over the internet and can't find an answer for this.

It would look something like this:

[image: Example 1 of 2]
[image: Example 2 of 2]

So basically there is text and if you click it it will make you talk.
Can anybody please tell me the `/give` command?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a command that will do that:

```
/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:["[\"\",{\"text\":\"Click Here\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/say Hello There\"}}]"],title:"Hello there",author:IronAnvil}
```

Though, I recommend using a book editor tool if you want more complications as formatting is tough.  [Here is the one I used for that command.](http://minecraft.tools/en/book.php)

Add a clickEvent that runs a command and use the say command.

If you want to see a little bit more complication, here is another command.  This one is long enough it will need to be run from a command block:

```
/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:["[\"\",{\"text\":\"Hello there:\\n\"},{\"text\":\"Click here\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/say Hello there\"},\"hoverEvent\":{\"action\":\"show_text\",\"value\":\"If you click here, you will say 'Hello there' in chat.\"}},{\"text\":\"\\n\\nGoodbye:\\n\",\"color\":\"reset\"},{\"text\":\"Click Here\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/say Goodbye\"},\"hoverEvent\":{\"action\":\"show_text\",\"value\":\"If you click here, you will say 'Goodbye' in chat.\"}},{\"text\":\"\\n\",\"color\":\"reset\"}]"],title:"Book of Speak",author:IronAnvil}
```

---

Edit:

Here are both commands again but the clickEvent does not specify a command so it just outputs to chat:

```
/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:["[\"\",{\"text\":\"Click Here\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"Hello There\"}}]"],title:"Hello there",author:IronAnvil}

/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:["[\"\",{\"text\":\"Hello there:\\n\"},{\"text\":\"Click here\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"Hello there\"},\"hoverEvent\":{\"action\":\"show_text\",\"value\":\"If you click here, you will say 'Hello there' in chat.\"}},{\"text\":\"\\n\\nGoodbye:\\n\",\"color\":\"reset\"},{\"text\":\"Click Here\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"Goodbye\"},\"hoverEvent\":{\"action\":\"show_text\",\"value\":\"If you click here, you will say 'Goodbye' in chat.\"}},{\"text\":\"\\n\",\"color\":\"reset\"}]"],title:"Book of Speak",author:IronAnvil}
```

Comment: That makes you use the /say command I want something that doesn't use the say command because it makes the [HeyItzAxel] hello instead of <HeyItzAxel> hello

Comment: I have made an edit that will output to chat without the say command.